# Uninstall application under /opt?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I have uninstalled `acroread 9.5.5-1precise1` in software center, but those under `/opt/Adobe/Reader9` seem intact:

```
/opt/Adobe/Reader9$ ls *
bin:
acroread

Browser:
HowTo  install_browser_plugin  intellinux

Reader:
AcroVersion  Cert  GlobalPrefs  help  IDTemplates  intellinux  JavaScripts  Legal  PDFSigQFormalRep.pdf  pmd.cer  Tracker

Resource:
CMap  Font  Icons  Linguistics  Shell  Support  TypeSupport
```

I don't remember how I installed adobe acrobat reader (by software center, or from some deb package?)

Can I remove the files in `/opt/Adobe/Reader9` safely?

How do you uninstall software installed under `/opt/` in general? Thanks.

---

```
$ dpkg -S acroread
oxygen-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/oxygen/64x64/apps/acroread.png
acroread-bin: /usr/share/man/man1/acroread.1.gz
gnome-orca: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/script.py
acroread-bin: /usr/bin/acroread
oxygen-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/oxygen/32x32/apps/acroread.png
gnome-orca: /usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/__init__.py
oxygen-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/oxygen/48x48/apps/acroread.png
oxygen-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/oxygen/16x16/apps/acroread.png
acroread-bin: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Resource/Shell/acroread.1.gz
acroread-bin: /usr/share/applications/acroread.desktop
gnome-orca: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/__init__.py
zsh: /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/X/_acroread
acroread-bin: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Resource/Shell/acroread_tab
acroread-bin: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread
gnome-orca: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/orca/scripts/apps/acroread
gnome-orca: /usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/apps/acroread
acroread-bin: /usr/share/doc/acroread-bin/copyright
acroread-bin: /usr/share/doc/acroread-bin
acroread-bin: /usr/share/doc/acroread-bin/changelog.Debian.gz
acroread-bin: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/acroread-bin
acroread-bin: /opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin/acroread
gnome-orca: /usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/script.py
oxygen-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/oxygen/128x128/apps/acroread.png
oxygen-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/oxygen/22x22/apps/acroread.png
acroread-bin: /etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh
```

Comment: Usually, when you install it in `/opt/` you should be able to remove it with a simple `rm -rfv`. But i would just `mv` it and give it a try. But with something like Adobe acrobat there should be a apt-purge package that does it for you.

Comment: I have installed it from a .deb and removing  it also  removed /opt/Adobe/ directory. I don't know why it didn't in your case.

Comment: @chrisjlee: `sudo apt-get purge acroread` doesn't remove the dir or its content.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dpkg -S` to detect whether a particular path is managed by dpkg or not. Some exceptions are: anything under `/var/`, `/etc/`, `/run/`, or `/boot` (which often contain generated files), and anything that is a symlink to something in `/etc/alternatives/`

Applications that don't follow standards are expected to be installed under `/opt`, regardless of whether they're packaged in a `.deb` or not.

Comment: Thanks. See my update to the end of my post. What shall I do now?

Comment: `apt-get purge acroread-bin` did remove `/opt/Adobe`. Wonder why `apt-get purge acroread` and uninstallation from software center didn't.

Comment: @Tim Because a Binary File `*-bin` comes directly from Adobe and is not in a repo, where as plain acroread came from a repo.

Comment: @eyoung100 or it's a dependency - removing one package doesn't remove dependencies (except in aptitude).

Comment: @eyoung100: how do you know "a Binary File `*-bin` comes directly from Adobe"? are there similar examples?

Comment: I can provide numerous examples: Du to license restrictions on Gentoo, [Firefox](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/www-client/firefox-bin), the old copy of [OpenOffice](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/app-office/openoffice-bin), and [Java](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/dev-java/oracle-jre-bin) are all binary files

Comment: @eyoung100 the way Gentoo uses `-bin` is significantly different than all other distros. On Debian, `-bin` signifies a package containing executables, rather than libraries, data, or headers (but it's usually built from the same source package as the others; imagine if `USE` flags for a package could be installed separately).

Comment: True but @Tim wanted to know what a bin file was.  Gentoo's version of `*-bin` is the same as Debian's.  The USE FLAGS cannot be set in a binary version, and as such is not compiled, it the same way that your bin is.